# Criar Índice Remissivo em Java gerando arquivo HTML?

Tags: java, estrutura-de-dados

Estava precisando criar um índice remissivo com um livro passado por parâmetro (`File`, `BufferedReader`).

Ate agora não consegui bons resultados, tenho apenas um código que gera um `TreeSet` com todas as palavras do texto passado por parâmetro. Estou tentando a 3 semanas fazer o código que pegue as palavras e guarde as linhas aonde elas aparecem e gere o arquivo HTML do índice remissivo.

`Read` é um `LineNumberReader`, palavras é um `TreeSet`.

Tenho encontrado problemas na hora de percorrer a lista gerada pelo metodo split e comparar com o texto palavra por palavra (este é o código que não consigo elaborar).

```
    while((line = read.readLine()) != null){
        line = line.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", " ").toLowerCase();
        split = line.split(" ");

        for(String s : split){
            if(s.length() >= 1 && !palavras.contains(s)){
                palavras.add(s);
            }
        }           
    }

    path.close();
    read.close();

    }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.getStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Caminho para o arquivo invalido!");

    }catch(IOException ex){
        ex.getStackTrace();
    }

    return palavras;  
}
```

Comment: Achou alguma solução? Poste como resposta para ajudar outras pessoas.

Answer (score 2):

Teu código tá quase lá, só acho que pra você conseguir o que pretende, ajudaria muito mudar a estrutura de dados "palavras" para um java.util.Map, ao invés de um java.util.Set. A questão é que você não quer guardar apenas as palavras, mas a relação existente entre cada palavra e uma lista de linhas (ou seja, uma lista de inteiros). Desta forma, eu redefini "palavras" da seguinte forma:

```
Map<String,Set<Integer>> palavras = new HashMap<String, Set<Integer>>();
```

Com esta estrutura você poderá salvar relações como:

- "bla" -> [1,3]
- "ble" -> [2]

Ou seja, a palavra "bla" foi encontrada na linha 1 e 3 enquanto a palavra "ble" foi encontrada na linha 2. Com isso, eu alterei seu "for" para adicionar uma nova entrada no mapa caso a palavra não já esteja lá, e adicionar apenas a página caso já exista:

```
for(String s : split){
    if(!palavras.keySet().contains(s)){
      Set<Integer> linhas = new TreeSet<Integer>();
          linhas.add(read.getLineNumber());
          palavras.put(s, linhas);
      } else {
          palavras.get(s).add(read.getLineNumber());
      }
}
```

Será que ajuda? Se precisar de mais algum esclarecimento é só perguntar nos comentários.